# MySQL single SELECT showing error in PHP but not in PHPMYADMIN

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

There are some questions on stackoverflow about it but only with insert, what about that? :

Sql in phpmyadmin:

```
SELECT logins.user as user,
logins.id as usid,
rozliczenia.godziny as godziny,
rozliczenia.stawka as stawka,
rozliczenia.premia as premia,
rozliczenia.premiainna as premiainna
FROM logins
LEFT JOIN rozliczenia
ON logins.id=rozliczenia.userid
AND DATE(rozliczenia.data) BETWEEN DATE('2015-01-01') AND DATE('2015-01-31')
WHERE logins.user NOT IN ('SUPERUSER', 'agata', 'tomek')
GROUP BY logins.user
ORDER BY logins.id
```

It works, but in php:

```
$sql = "SELECT logins.user as user, logins.id as usid, rozliczenia.godziny as godziny, rozliczenia.stawka as stawka, rozliczenia.premia as premia, rozliczenia.premiainna as premiainna FROM logins LEFT JOIN rozliczenia ON logins.id=rozliczenia.userid AND DATE(rozliczenia.data) BETWEEN DATE('2015-10-01') AND DATE('2015-10-31') WHERE logins.user NOT IN ('SUPERUSER', 'agata', 'tomek') GROUP BY logins.user ORDER BY logins.id;";
//The same sql
if(!$result = $polaczenie->query($sql)){
    return FALSE;
}
while ($rowV = $result->fetch_array())
{
...
```

It kinda works, but returns:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '2015-10-01') AND DATE('2015-10-31') WHERE `logins`.`user` NOT IN ('SUPERUSER', '' at line 1

What's wrong?

Know all of a sudden more of my scripts return that error. I'm tired of this

**EDIT**

When I delete

```
WHERE logins.user NOT IN ('SUPERUSER', 'agata', 'tomek')
GROUP BY logins.user
ORDER BY logins.id
```

it works, but I need it. If I delete only where or only grouop, it doesn't change anything

Comment: dont understand why you are using the DATE() function, 2015-10-01 is already a date

Comment: What versions of PHP, MySQL, and PHPMyAdmin are you using? As @Dagon said, try removing the DATE() calls around your date strings and possibly the `rozliczenia.data` field.

Comment: @Dagon It's xampp control panel 3.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was weird, but when i rewrited my code, it worked

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i'm wrong but, your first AND should be after your WHERE.